# 1080p video freezes and jams the ubuntu 16.04 machine

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, video

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04LTS from 14.04. I had severe problem watching 1080p videos in my 14.04, I thought the situation would be better with the new OS but it seems to be the same. I have a dual-boot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 and running my videos on VLC.

I was wondering is it slowing down because it's a dual boot or things can be fixed other ways?

Comment: Which video card do you have? And do you have the same issue with SMPlayer?

Comment: description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)

Comment: i have same issues with every player